# Sending list as parameter to API method

Tags: c#, arrays, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

This is the model and code block I use and they work fine.

```
public class PostClass
{
    public string VariantName { get; set; }
    public string VariantNames { get; set; }
}

HttpWebRequest httpWebRequestContent = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://localhost:44000/api/Variant/Example");

httpWebRequestContent.ContentType = "application/json";
httpWebRequestContent.Accept = "application/json";
httpWebRequestContent.PreAuthenticate = true;
httpWebRequestContent.Method = "POST";

using (StreamWriter streamWriterContent = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequestContent.GetRequestStream()))
{
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
                {
                    VariantName = model.VariantName,
                    VariantDetailNames = model.VariantDetailNames
                });
    streamWriterContent.Write(json);
}
```

My question is how can I send this list as parameter in serialize part of my code?

```
List<PostClass> modelList
```

Comment: Simple method is to make a CSV string : VariantDetailNames = string.Join(",",model.VariantDetailNames)

Comment: Could you please clarify, what exactly are you going to achieve?

Comment: In .NET Core, WebRequest is just a legacy wrapper over HttpClient so this code is *less* efficient than using HttpClient. `HttpClient.PostAsJsonAsync()` can send anything as JSON in a single line of code. The `JsonContent` class can be used to send anything as JSON without manually serializing to a temporary string first

Comment: What does the remote API expect? Even with the obsolete WebRequest, there's no problem passing a `List<PostClass>` to `JsonConvert.SerializeObject`, eg `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(modelList)`. The code will be slower and use more memory but it would still work. If the API doesn't accept arrays, there's no way to make it accept an array

Answer (score 1):

From [WebRequest.Create Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webrequest.create?view=net-7.0) we can see

> WebRequest, HttpWebRequest, ServicePoint, and WebClient are obsolete.
> Use HttpClient instead.

Below is a work demo you can refer to it. Hope it can help.

HomeController:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> IndexAsync()
 {
     var json = new List<PostClass>() {
     new PostClass() { VariantName="dd",VariantNames="hh"},
     new PostClass() { VariantName="dd2",VariantNames="hh2"}};

     StringContent content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

     HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
     var response2 = await httpClient.PostAsync("https://localhost:7277/api/Variant", content);
     
     return Ok();
 }
```

VariantController:

```
 [Route("api/[controller]")]
 [ApiController]
 public class VariantController : ControllerBase
 {
     [HttpPost]
     public IActionResult Example(List<PostClass> modelList)
     {
         //..... function going here
         return Ok();  
     }
 }
```

result:
[image]

You can read [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-7.0)  to know more.

**Update :**

Change the

```
 StringContent content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

into

```
 JsonContent content = JsonContent.Create(json);
```

Comment: There's no need to serialize to a string first. You can return a `JsonContent` which takes care of serializing directly to JSON without a temporary string, reducing allocations

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  Thank you for your reminder. I update in my answer.